# Regex lookaheads (or behinds) matching foo bar or bar foo

Tags: regex

I want to match either `foo bar baz` *or* `bar baz foo`. `foo` can be in either position, but it must be present. I'm not too familiar with lookaheads, and look behinds, but I feel like that's got to be the way to do it. Any tips?

Comment: Is "bar baz" a constant and foo the pre or post fix?  Or is bar baz just filler where you want your string to start or end with foo?

Comment: @Bohemian: It _can_ be in both positions, but probably won't.

Comment: @EricH: `bar baz` would be end up being it's own set of options  (`bar|baz` would have been more accurate), but that part has to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but the following should work:

```
/^(?=.*foo)(foo )?bar baz( foo)?$/
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/7wEVNi5G1Q

Alternatively, you can just use `|` to match one option or the other:

```
/foo bar baz|bar baz foo/
```

Comment: I like the `/^(?=.*foo)(foo )?` bit, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the bar baz might actually be something complicated, I at least want to suggest a cleaner solution for more complicated cases: build the regex:

```
$foo = 'foo'
$barbaz = 'bar baz'
$regex = "($foo $barbaz)|($barbaz $foo)"
```

translate to your language of choice ;) I'm always surprised when I see a regex for an url or email totally written out, why not build it, that way it stays debuggable...

Comment: Great idea. That `bar baz` bit is, indeed, more complicated than I made it sound. I'll try building it as you suggested later on.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound "too simple", but how about this?

```
(foo bar baz|bar baz foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(foo bar baz|bar baz foo)`  would work and is way easier to read than using look aheads or look behinds.

Edit after comments:

```
(foo (bar|baz)|(bar|baz) foo)
```